# Completely remove VSS binding from the solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe

I copied the entire ASP.Net solution directory to a new location and started with the process of **removing the VSS bindings** as under:

1. Removed all files having extensions as `*.scc`, `*.vspscc` and `*.vssscc`
2. Removed the follwing 4 keys from the `*.csproj` files:

> SccProjectName, SccLocalPath, SccAuxPath, and SccProvider.

Thereafter when I opened my solution it threw an error / warning:

> The solution appears to be under source control, but its binding information cannot be found. It is possible that the MSSCCPRJ.SCC file or another item that holds the source control settings for the solution, has been deleted. Because it is not possible to recover this missing information automatically, the projects whose bindings are missing will be treated as not under source control.

Also, please note I did not find the below line / section in any of the `*.csproj` files:

> GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl) = preSolution

I just want to ensure that I don't see that error / warning every time I open the solution. How to achieve that? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

The `GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl) = preSolution` section is held within the solution file (.sln).

You may find you also have some source control settings in the `ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject` section such as `SccProjectName`, `SccLocalPath` and `SccProvider`.